# Get template function type

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, types

I'm new in using templates in C++, I want to do different things depending on type used between `<` and `>`, so `function<int>()` and `function<char>()` won't do the same things.
How can I achieve this?

```
template<typename T> T* function()
{
    if(/*T is int*/)
    {
        //...
    }
    if(/*T is char*/)
    {
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your case, where `T` cannot be deduced from the call, specialisations are the way to go (as the answers suggest). However, if you actually use `T` in the parameters and have it deduced, you'd be better off using plain overloads and [avoiding function template specialisation](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use explicit specialization of your function template:

```
template<class T> T* function() {
};

template<> int* function<int>() {
    // your int* function code here
};

template<> char* function<char>() {
    // your char* function code here
};
```

Comment: Why not just overload? Overloading is generally preferable to function template specialization.

Comment: You can't overload on just a return value

Comment: "Why not just overload?" You can only overload on parameter types, not on return type.

Comment: Right, didn't notice the type wasn't used in the parameters.

Comment: You cannot overload the entire function, but you can tag dispatch within.

Comment: Specializing functions is somehow tricky. Even at the cost of extra typing, I would better have the function dispatch to a class template (static member function inside a class template) and do the specializations there.

Answer (score 5):

Create **[template specializations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwyxac18.aspx)**:

```
template<typename T> T* function()
{
 //general case general code
}

template<> int* function<int>()
{
  //specialization for int case.
}

template<> char* function<char>()
{
  //specialization for char case.
}
```

Comment: @billz . yes, do u have a compiler? template specialization with explicitly specifying the template argument.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices involves tag dispatch, because specialization is tricky.

Tag dispatch is easier to use quite often:

```
template<typename T>
T* only_if_int( std::true_type is_int )
{
  // code for T is int.
  // pass other variables that need to be changed/read above
}
T* only_if_int( std::false_type ) {return nullptr;}
template<typename T>
T* only_if_char( std::true_type is_char )
{
  // code for T is char.
  // pass other variables that need to be changed/read above
}
T* only_if_char( std::false_type ) {return nullptr;}
template<typename T> T* function()
{
  T* retval = only_if_int( std::is_same<T, int>() );
  if (retval) return retval;
  retval = only_if_char( std::is_same<T, char>() );
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: This is more generic. But i dint understand the "specialization is tricky" part. why is it tricky?Could you please add that part to the answer as well. i could have this answer as a ref?. Thanks

Comment: @Kroushik Specialization of functions is tricky because it is easy to get wrong!  Specialization *looks* sort of like overloading, but it is not overloading and it operates on different rules.  The overlap of overloading and specialization can cause serious brain teaser "why doesn't this work" problems.  Tag dispatch avoids this problem by not specializing, and using overload dispatch to do the job instead, which reduces the number of pages of the C++ standard you need memorized to understand what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
T Add(T n1, T n2)
{
    T result;
    result = n1 + n2;

    return result;
}
```

For In detail understanding of template, go through the below link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1

Answer (score -1):

you can define overloaded functions something like this:

```
#define INTT  0
#define CHARR 1
template<typename T>
T* function()
{
int type;
type = findtype(T);
//do remaining things based on the return type

}

int findType(int a)
{
return INTT;
}

int findType(char a)
{
return CHARR;
}
```